# cannot import name pool theano

Tags: python, theano, importerror

as written in the title, I cannot import pool

specifically,

```
from theano.tensor.signal import pool
```

doesn't work.

It says

```
ImportError: cannot import name pool
```

I tried to update theano by

```
sudo pip install git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git --upgrade --no-deps
```

Then, it shows 'Successfully installed Theano-0.9.0.dev2' but still cannot import pool.

When I write these code in the python interpreter

```
import theano
theano.__version__
```

Then it says '0.7.0.dev-f986e0dd35f .... '
I think still I am using 0.7.0 version but I don't know how to do.

Would you plz tell me how to solve importing error?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have two Pythons installed on your system, one of them locally and the other globally. When you `sudo pip install`, you install the latest Theano for your global installation of Python. However, when you run Python, you run the local Python with the old version of the Theano.